# How To Automate - Azure DevOps - Boards Items / Work Items

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am new to Azure DevOps / boards.
I have loaded (csv) a bunch of Work Items (Boards -> Work Items).
Now when I go to Boards (Boards -> Boards), I need to create new items and link to existing work items...

Is there a way to automate Boards -> Boards item and Boards -> Work Items?
I feel like this is keypunching twice the same info... but I guess I do not correctly understand the concept/difference between these 2 sections.

I am just trying to create my boards and work items and assign them to my sprints.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with Excel, connected to your instance. You can create a hierarchy of work items inside the XLSX file, with the field `Title 1` being the parent, and `Title 2` being the child task. Make sure your `List type` is set to "Tree" to ensure you get the parent/child relationships. Once you have set up your data, you're ready to publish. Before you proceed to the next step, save the file as something like "sprint workitem template".

[image]

Now from the Teams bar in Excel, click `Publish`.

[image]

The next step is the most important. Close the sheet, **without** saving. If you save it, the ID's assigned to the work items will become static.